# Quantifying a manifold folding unto itself

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, model-evaluation, k-nearest-neighbour, manifold-learning

I have a dataset of ~7k scattered points in 3D which represents a manifold that may or may not "fold unto itself". Here's an example where this *does* happen (look at the top-right yellow triangles):

[image]

My ultimate goal is to have a metric to compare many such datasets, in order to optimize the hyperparameters leading to the formation of this hypersurface/manifold/volume, while minimizing the *unwanted* folding.

One way to detect whether such folding occurs is by examining the errors when performing leave-one-out cross-validation. Specifically, we can quantify the folding, by **a)** interpolating the value (*color*) of each point based on `k` nearest neighbors; **b)** comparing it the interpolated and correct value; and **c)** aggregating the errors.

When I tried implementing this in MATLAB, using a combination of `fitcknn`, `crossval` and `kfoldLoss`, processing took on the order of minutes - which is unacceptably slow - as I must be able to perform this error computation on the order of a second or less. I know about CUDA-based algorithms for accelerated knn search<sup>[1](https://github.com/vincentfpgarcia/kNN-CUDA)</sup>. However, as I don't come from this field I can't tell if I can leverage a fast knn search algorithm to speed up the leave-one-out error computation. (In fact, I don't even know if this is the most suitable approach to the problem.)

Is there something "costly" I can compute once for each dataset (kdtree? pairwise distances?) and use *that* for fast computation of the aggregate error? How else can I speed this up?

I would also be happy to hear about any other algorithm that could quantify the folding effect.

Comment: If you were asking for code, a function, some software, etc., that would be off topic here.  However, "if I can leverage a fast knn search algorithm to speed up the leave-one-out error computation", & "Is there something 'costly' I can compute once for each dataset (kdtree? pairwise distances?) and use that for fast computation of the aggregate error? How else can I speed this up?", are not really asking for code, AFAICT. Those seem like good, & on topic, questions for the site. Thanks for asking, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up approximating cross-validation using [inverse-distance-weighted (IDW) interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) using the nearest neighbors. This produced useful results and was also fast to compute. Below is the outline of the implementation:

#### Part 1: Find K nearest neighbors of each point

1. Decide on the amount of nearest neighbors, `K`, to use.
2. Compute squared Euclidean distances between all points. (Note: this is slightly faster than the actual distances, since we avoid taking the root.)
3. Establish the indices of the `K` nearest neighbors, for each point.

#### Part 2: Find internal and boundary points

4. Find a **non-convex** hull of the set of points. Points on the boundary will be known as "*boundary points*" and rest will be "*internal points*". (Note: I know this is easier said than done. I used MATLAB's [`boundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) with a shrink factor of `1`.)

#### Part 3: Perform interpolation and compute error

5. Compute the value at each **internal** point as a weighted sum of the values of its `K` neighbors, where the weights are the inverse distances in some power `P`. Note: using only the internal points is crucial for correctness, since IDW, which doesn't use/store direction information, cannot extrapolate correctly (as opposed to [trilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation), for example).
6. Subtract the interpolated value from the known value, at each point, to obtain the error.

For visualization purposes, a histogram appeared useful. For computational purposes, a mean absolute error appeared useful.

Comment: Wow, this is great!  Thanks for sharing what you found.  This could be very useful for a graph drawing library I'm working on.

Comment: @micahscopes Thank you for writing that! This was developed as part of a research direction we ended up abandoning (for administrative reasons). I'm really happy that someone else found it useful. Please do share a link to the library if/when it's public.